# Cross Domain tracking on a Form not working with ._linkbyPost

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain, web-analytics

I'm having an issue with my cross-domain tracking on a form.  I have a hotel client who has a form that submits to one of two booking engines depending on the options selected.  However, from what I can tell, it doesn't look like the form is set up in a traditional way as it does not contain an "action," but rather an "href."  Code below.

```
<!--start quicksearch -->
<div id="qs" align="center">
      <div align="center"><img src="images/qs_title.gif" alt="Quick Search">
          <table width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <!--<form  method="post">--><form  method="post" onsubmit="pageTracker._linkByPost(this);">

....

<td width="35%" valign="bottom"><div align="left"><a href="javascript:sendToCBE();"><img src="quicksearch/continue-buttom_dreams.gif" alt="Continue" width="83" height="24" border="0" onclick="mojo_roi('continue'); pageTracker._trackEvent('Button', 'Click', 'QuickSearchWidget');"></a></div></td>
                </tr>

            </table></td>
          </tr>
        </form>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end quick search-->
```

My feeling is that because there is not an "action" to call, that it is not passing along any cookie information.  Every other form on other websites I have used as a reference use an "action."  Any thoughts?  Is the ._linkbyPost in the correct position or does it need to be moved?

Any and all insight would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will not work. Google Analytics is relying on native usage of the POST functionality.

The absence of an "action" suggests that the form is being managed by JavaScript using non-native form functionality. So, you need to adjust the JavaScript logic that manages the form (presumably, the function called `sendToCBE`.

`_linkByPost` is a function that tries to do everything for the 99% of use cases, but, in this case, it doesn't help.

You'll need to do some custom query string adjustment with [`_getLinkerUrl`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._getLinkerUrl)

That'll look something like (pseudocode):

```
function submit_redirect_function(){
     var url = .... // the logic that creates the URL you're redirecting to onsubmit
     url = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(url); //appends the linker query string to the URL. 
     window.location = url;
}
```

If you share more of the details of how this form is implemented (for example, what `sendToCBE` or `mojo_roi` do exactly, I can provide more specific guidance.

Comment: Truthfully, I'm not sure what mojo_roi does, but I think it's similar to the Event Tracking.  As for the SendToCBE code, that is in a Javascript Document that looks like:

    
    `// JavaScript Document
    function popup_no_status(loc)  
    {  
    var windowW=1000 
    var windowH=700 
    s = "width="+windowW+",height="+windowH+",status=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes"; 
    mywin = window.open(loc ,'CBE', s); 
    mywin.focus();  
    }`

Does this help any?

Comment: Yep. You should be able to wrap the `loc` in the `window.open` statement with `pageTracker._getLinkerUrl`. Like, `window.open(pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(loc), "CBE", s);`.

Comment: By adding that code, should this solve the cross-domain tracking issue?  Is there anything I need to customize within the query string in order to make this work?  Does `loc` need to be set as something specific? Does the LinkerURL need to be set somewhere within the HTML or this document? As you can probably tell, I'm not a js expert by any means.

Comment: @GlennB you should talk to your developer, but, I'm assuming `loc` is the URL you're redirecting to. the `pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(loc)` will return the same URL but with the special linker URL parameters appended.

Comment: Excellent, definitely much appreciated!

Comment: The code has been implemented but it looks as though it did not work successfully in passing along the cookies for cross-domain tracking.  Is there any reason this would not work?